# Unicode characters on JSON string with swift 3 and Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift3, alamofire

I'm dealing with this issue here.
I have make a json request with alamofire and inside my json there are some characters like `u00b` etc. Which is greek language.
Although when i print the dictionary i cant see the correct string like "αβγ" but their unicode characters.

Which is the proper way with alamofire to unicode all the text that i get to utf-8 so i can print out the proper characters??

The following code is the request that i make.

```
func getManPerf() {
    Alamofire.request(baseurl, method: .get, parameters: ["action": "categories", "subaction": "getproducts", "category_id": "11", "limit": "0,30"]).responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
        if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
            let result = responseData.result
            print(result)

            if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>{
                if let list = dict["products_in_category"] as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {

                    for obj in list {
                        let manPerfumes = Products(productDict: obj)
                        self.manPerfumeData.append(manPerfumes)
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async{
                        self.manPerfumeCV.reloadData()

                    }


                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

What changes do i have to make to my code so it can bring me the correct data? Thanks!

Comment: Print `dict` rather than `result`. The UTF8 characters in the dictionary are correct.

Comment: @vadian yes i've also printed `dict` and i see the `u00b` like characters.

Comment: That's only the print-to-console representation. Assign a string value to a label then you will see the proper characters.

Comment: @vadian the thing is that i get some urls and i'm trying to download images. And any link that has these type of characters it doesnt download the image.

Comment: You need to escape / percent encode the URL accordingly. `URL(string:` is not sufficient.

Comment: @vadian you are totaly correct in association with the answer of Emptyless below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format the string with UTF-8 before appending ;)

```
let manPerfumesUTF = String(UTF8String: manPerfumes.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))
```

Example in playgrounds:

```
class Products {

    let _name : String

    init(productDict : [String : String]) {

        self._name = productDict["name"] ?? "error"
    }

}

let productDict = ["name" : "Hugo Boss"]
let productDictWithUTF8 = ["name" : "\u{03b2}\u{03b5}\u{03b5}\u{03c1}"]

let hugoBoss = Products(productDict: productDict)
let greekParfume = Products(productDict: productDictWithUTF8)
print(hugoBoss._name)      // Hugo Boss
print(greekParfume._name)  // βεερ
```

Comment: there is an error that `Value of type Products has no member of cStringUsingEncoding` and products is my model class.

Comment: Ow sorry i was reading the code wrong. in your init function of your Products class. You have to change the string that you want to display using UTF-8. So for example: ' if let productName = productDict["product_name"] { self.productName = String(UTF8String: productName.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)) '

Comment: in swift 3 this is my code for product name for example 
`  if let productName = productDict["name"] as? String {
            self._name = productName
        }`

and i'm trying to put your example but i get an error

Comment: in association with the answer of @vadian i got the correct result. thanks!

Comment: I have added an example ;)

Comment: Your String -> UTF-8 -> String dance does not change *anything.* This is just misleading, you would get exactly the same result (in your sample code) with `self._name =  productDict["name"] ?? "error"` .

Comment: I had to check it but you are right, in the summer I had sort of the same problem and found this solution somewhere on SO. Seems like it isn't needed (anymore?)

Comment: Even `print(productDictWithUTF8["name"]!)` prints `βεερ`. – The only "problem" is (as indicated in the comments below the question) that printing a *dictionary* uses escape sequences for non-ASCII characters. Printing a *string* works as expected. So there is actually no problem at all.